# Is it possible to do active noise cancellation of ambient noise while playing back audio through headphones?

Tags: 16.04

I understand that it is possible to enable echo cancellation with PulseAudio but it seems that this is only enabled when recording audio from a microphone via a video recorder or other tool.

What I am curious (looking for) is to achieve echo/noise cancellation via the mic of ambient noise (office noise for example). Such that the noise cancellation output is fed to the current audio output (e.g. my headphones) and this way I can cancel out ambient noise while listening to audio on my headphones.

Has anyone achieved this? Is this even possible?